# How do I design my model (where I need to represent a hash or array as part of the attributes)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and database design in general. Here's what I'm trying to do: I want to create a model, call it Command, which represents a command that can be used on a command line. So each command has the command itself and a description of what it does. As we all know, though, commands have flags/options. I want to be able to associate the many flags along with their descriptions with each command. Can I somehow include the hash/array that will store these flags/options as part of the model or do I have to create a separate model for Flags and represent each command as having many flags?

Any advice/illumination would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT -

So I've heard that I can use serialized attributes. If I do this, how can I get my hash to be represented as an inner object (with the string/values) in the json representation of my model?

Answer (score 4):

Various commands use same flags. Flags like `-e`, `-i` are common to many commands. Lets take the example of `ps -e` and `strace -e`, where the same flag is used by two different commands for two different purposes. To achieve a proper database design where each flag depends on the command it is being used. This sounds like a good example of a `has_and_belongs_to_many`(habtm) association, (as each command has many flags and each flag can appear for many commands).

Comment: Thanks Alok! So, in my case I'll use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both models, right? E.g in my Command class i'll have: `has_and_belongs_to_many :flag` and in my Flag class I'll have: `has_and_belongs_to_many :command` ?

Comment: Yes, specifying the association in both the models would also give you the added benefit of finding all flags for a command and all commands where the flag is used. Ideally, if you just follow the naming convention of naming the join table Rails way then the association would work, specifying the association would give you these powerful methods to filter data as and when required instead of resorting to conditions in AR queries or even worse raw SQL.

Comment: How do I then associate a specific flag with a specific command? I have to build the association into the model?

Comment: In has_and_belongs_to_many join table, you can specify the flag_id and the command_id. There is a very nice example at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association